# Atualizar edmx do banco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Fiz um update model from database em meu edmx. Bem, o campo que eu havia acrescentado na tabela aparece no diagrama, porem no cs da entidade não, continua com os campos antigos. O que faço, acrescento na mão? Esse é o meu cs

```
public partial class T_Script
    {
        public int IDScript { get; set; }
        public string Script { get; set; }
        public string NomeScript { get; set; }
        public string TituloScript { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Ativo { get; set; }
    }
```

Esta faltando o novo campo, mas já existe no diagrama. O novo campo é do tipo smallint no BD. Acho que falta isso:

```
public Nullable<int> TipoStatus { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que gerar as entidades novamente... tente clicar com o botão direito sobre o EDMX, deve haver um menu chamado `Run Custom Tool`.

Esse item do menu serve para rodar a ferramenta para gerar as entidades, que no caso, se a propriedade `Custom Tool` estiver como `EntityModelCodeGenerator`, será o `EdmGen.exe`.

**Referência**

- [Generated Code Overview (Entity Data Model Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc982041%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [How to: Validate an .edmx File (Entity Data Model Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716694%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Tem certeza que não tem nenhum erro no EDMX?

Comment: Tipo alguma propriedade que antes existia, mas agora não está mais mapeada... é comum quando se remove ou renomeia colunas no banco de dados.

Comment: Clica com o direito no plano de fundo da janela de visualização do EDMX, e clique no item de menu `Validate`. Abra a janela que lista os erros, com título `Error List` (`CTRL` + `W` + `E`)... ali estarão os erros.

Comment: Quais são os warnings?

Comment: Recriei o edmx e agora está pk

Comment: Os warnings eram todos de css. Já os resolvi também

Comment: Como eu finalizo? A resposta do Miguel me ajudou muito em aprender mais uma ferramenta, mas o gran finale veio em recriar. Não vejo nenhum problema em clicar na resposta do Miguel, mas quero fazer do jeito certo, pois já fui muito penalizado nesse forum

Comment: Basta marcar as resposta do Miguel como a correta que fica embaixo das setas de votação da resposta.

Comment: Para verificar qual é o problema, se você ainda tiver em mãos o EDMX antigo, antes de recriá-lo, usar uma ferramenta de DIFF, tal como o WinMerge, para saber o que diferencia um EDMX que funciona de outro que não funciona.

Comment: Só queria dizer @pnet, que a solução melhor para trabalhar com edmx é essa que o @MiguelAngelo te passou, porque no máximo tem como atualizar mediante mudança no banco, dando um refresh no edmx. Mexer nesse `edmx` na mão não seria recomendável pelo fator erro e codificação não muito trivial.

Comment: Eu já tentei mexer no EDMX na mão algumas vezes... em todas eu me arrempedi... =D  Quando eu sugeri de @pnet fazer um diff nos arquivos edmx, na verdade era só pra detectar qual seria o possível problema. Tipo, se tiver um mapeamento a uma coluna que não existe será fácil identificar isso com o diff... mas ai depois ele poderia ir no designer e tentar remover o mapeamento, sem editar o edmx na mão.